# Setting x:Name on the UserControl tag inside a UserControl sometimes crashes the application

Tags: silverlight

I've created a UserControl named Marked. The code for the control is :

```
<UserControl .... x:Name="marker">
   <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" x:Name="LayoutRoot">

      <Image Source="{Binding Path=MarkSource, ElementName = marker}" Visiblity="{Binding Path=IsMarked}"/>  

   </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

In the code behind I've set two dependency properties: MarkSource and IsMarked.

When I use the control I do something like this:

```
<my:Marker MarkSource="mark.jpg" IsMarked = {Binding Path=Person.IsActive}/>
```

The problem is:
1. The custom control works.
2. Sometimes when I'm starting the application I receive the following error: Xaml tree error the name **marker** already exits.

when I restart the application it works correctly.

I've tried removing the x: from the x:Name="marker" to Name="marker" but the binding on the image doesn't work. 
I've tried setting up binding in the code behind, it also doesn't work.

What is the problem with the x:Name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to give `x:Name` to your Image control.
Remove `x:Name` from your `UserControl`.
In code behind set `DataContext` of your image to `this`.
Remove `ElementName = marker` in your binding.

Comment: Samvel you did it. Thanx mate.